# ImageView intent share not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to share an image to whatsAPP. my code is below:

```
 Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("/storage/sdcard1/image.jpg");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("image/jpeg");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
 intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

But it is not working. When I tried esnding text field it works fine using the code below

```
 Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        String text = textValue.getText().toString();
                        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

How can I share this imageView?

Comment: change your uri to this Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("file:///storage/sdcard1/image.jpg");

Comment: change `waIntent.setType("text/plain")`  to `waIntent.setType("Image/*")`

Comment: @user1688181 tried it crashes app

Comment: @prabhakaran both r different. I am talking about first block, second is working fine. image/* tried no use

Comment: what is `image.jpg` you have that file or saving dynamically ??

Comment: It is actually getting dynamically. For convenience here i directly put it

Comment: @prabhakaran help me buddy

Comment: @androidsuckzzz did you check this

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line:**

```
File sharefile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg");
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(sharefile);
```

**in Manifest Add this permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```